# Google Calendar api V3 authorization

Tags: email, passwords, authorization, google-calendar-api

In google calendar api v3 create credentials to google console developer for access to calendar.
In other e-mails can not do these steps, only have the login data (email and password).

It is possible connect my app like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question is how users login to your application? Is it just with user id and password or with client ID?

When you register your application in Google Developers Console, Google provides client ID and a client secret. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data. For the first time user(of your application) logins with the email and password. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) for the documentation.

Let me know if your question is different.

Comment: Yes it is, but I don't understand how make the level of programming? I don't find example in google to explain to me the java code!

Comment: Here is the link https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2. Hope this helps.